# PHP, Can't find a way to wait a value of external response

Tags: php

In my site there's a JS script, This script contact with external site to load some values related with captcha challenge, After this script loads variables and their values, This script will make a hidden input and this input has a name and id and token value!

The problem is that the script takes time to load, sometimes 6 to 10 seconds! depends on server speed! I made a php function, This function has the ability to check if that script loaded or not, Here is my code

The function check the value of this element `$_POST["fc-token"];`, If its value wasn't empty that means the script is already loaded

```
 function check_s(){
     $session_token = $_POST["fc-token"];
    if(!empty($session_token)){
        echo "Loaded";
    }else{
        $counter = 1;
        while($counter !== 10){
            sleep(1);
            $session_token = $_POST["fc-token"];
            if(!empty($session_token)){
                $counter = 5;
    
                break;
            }else{
                $counter = $counter + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
```

I don't know why this function stopped my whole site! everything won't load like js script and other scripts, And after 10 seconds the script will start loading! Idk why this function didn't allow anything to load!

So Is there a way to solve this matter?

Comment: Sounds like you have a serious problem with your architecture. The PHP source shouldn't be affected by any Javascript in any way. This should be solved in the frontend, where JS gives you Promises and so on. Your POST logic shouldn't be affected by it rather than checking the posted values.

Comment: @maio290 Thank you very much! Do you think multithreading will solve this problem?

Comment: Consider setting [time limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to 0.

Comment: @Luxury Promises are asynchronous by nature. I think the best approach here is to await the Captcha script and then fire the POST request to your backend. Everything else seems unusual and impractical to me.

Comment: @maio290 I will make a JS Script to wait that value before sending post request and thank you again. Good luck

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thank you for your response! I already did it, but in vain. gg